# Fazer com que o usuario insira uma informação

Tags: batch

Eu gostaria de saber como faço para que na tela do *script* em Batch apareça:

> "por favor insira seu nome"

Agradeço, qualquer ajuda é bem-vinda

Comment: Ele não permite que alguem insira nada :/

Answer (score 0):

Use o [`set`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)

```
@echo off
set /p NOME="Por favor insira seu nome: "

echo Bem-vindo %NOME%
```

O `/p` é para exibir uma mensagem antes de fazer a leitura da entrada do usuário.